# Inherit a class present in plugin to the app controller in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I want to Inherit a  controller present in plugin of cakephp in my app/xyz_controller class.Is it possible.Can somebody help me.

Comment: Something you should _definitely_ not be doing. Your controller should only be extended from the AppController. I've never come across a reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use some class functionality you can import it but inheriting a class in a controller is not a good practice, as PHP doesn't support multiple inheritance you'll lose all functionality Controller class provides.